# Database design advice

Tags: sql, database-design

I have a working SQLite database that holds information about video files.  The current design is as pictured below.  However, the boss has decided to make some changes.

[image]

The **FileProperties** table currently uses the file name as the primary key.  However, the PK now must be a compound key of both **fileName** and (file) **location**, which makes more sense anyway.

If this is done, what would be the best way to reference this compound key as a foreign key in the other tables?  I was thinking of either creating a separate table that holds an auto-incrementing primary key, **fileName** and **location**.  Then the PK can be used as a foreign key reference with all the other tables.

Or, make **fileName** and **location** a composite key in the current **FileProperties** table and add a new field that can be used as a reference and this field must be auto-incrementing and unique in the table.

I haven't had much practical experience with designing databases so any advice with my problem or my current design would be very welcome.

Comment: Be sure that your filename and location are big enough.  If "location" is a path, then it might well be bigger than 50.  In addition, NVARCHAR might be a better choice for file names.

Comment: +1 Blazes. NVARCHAR should be the default unless there is a large likelihood that a much larger space would be needed. In particular with Oracle - where text fields are stored as Large OBjects, which are a pain to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely use an auto-incrementing primary key. To ensure data integrity, create a unique index across the (filename,location) columns.

The [following wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_key) talks briefly about the pros and cons of a natural key. A natural key is a key taken directly from the data. In your case, that would be the composite key of (filename,location). In short, a natural key reduces physical space required by the data, at the cost of propagating changes to the key across all relations.

I (nearly) always have an auto-incrementing id on a table, even if there is a natural key available to be used.

Answer (score 3):

Add auto-incremented FileId primary key.
Add unique constraint for Location + FileName.
Avoid using compound primary keys.